# How to use the collection field type in Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'have been trying to use thr vollevtion field type in my Symfony 2 form, but it doesn't work. I already asked the same question sometime ago, but I didn't get the answer I wanted. I reed the documentation again (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html), but I still got the same probleme.

I already explane everything inside my other post, so here it is:

[How to integrate multiple entity in form in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504579/how-to-integrate-multiple-entity-in-form-in-symfony-2)

Please, someone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps you out

**ParentType:**

```
->add('funding', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new FundingType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true))
```

**ChildType:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', 'text', array(   
                'label' => 'Funding'));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Funding',
            ));
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
$funding = new Funding();
$project->getFunding()->add($funding);
```

**Twig**

```
 <div class="funding" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.funding.vars.prototype)|e}}">
       {% for funding in form.funding %}
              {{ form_row(funding.type) }}
       {% endfor %}
 </div>

<script>
// Funding

// setup an "add a tag" link
var $addFundingLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_funding_link">Add Funding type</a>');
var $newLinkLi1 = $('<p></p>').append($addFundingLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
   var $collectionHolder1 = $('div.funding');

    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    $collectionHolder1.append($newLinkLi1);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    $collectionHolder1.data('index1', $collectionHolder1.find(':input').length);

    $addFundingLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see code block below)
        addFundingForm($collectionHolder1, $newLinkLi1);
    });


});

function addFundingForm($collectionHolder1, $newLinkLi1) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder1.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index1 = $collectionHolder1.data('index1');

    // Replace '$$name$$' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm1 = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index1);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder1.data('index1', index1 + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi1 = $('<p></p>').append(newForm1);

    // also add a remove button, just for this example
    $newFormLi1.append('<a href="#" class="remove-funding">Delete</a>');

    $newLinkLi1.before($newFormLi1);

    // handle the removal, just for this example
    $('.remove-funding').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().remove();

        return false;
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! My problem was that I was using configureOptions insted of setDefaultOptions.